# cannot test appflow live update in ionic capacitor

Tags: android, vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic-appflow

This is the sample app repo.
https://github.com/shahabgohar/test_live_update

I installed this package for capacitor. please check.
https://ionic.io/docs/appflow/deploy/setup/capacitor-sdk

Then I set my capacitor configuration. please check capacitor.config

then I made test commit and installed that on android simulator for testing.
For example that commit has a p tag with hello world.

Now my app is still open in android simulator. then I made another commit and made web build out of it using following instruction.
https://ionic.io/docs/appflow/deploy/builds

Now my android simulator app which has older commit should update on app launch. But it is not doing any of that.
Please help